# a percentage sign shortcut to user desktop? (eg. %USERPROFILE% or %SYSTEMROOT%)

Tags: windows, file, filesystems

So I have been writing a short batch script to execute on multiple Windows 10 computers with desktop file location located differently. I cannot just insert my current desktop directory into the script and expect it to work on other machines as the directory includes username (`"C:\Users\user_A\Desktop"` and `"C:\Users\user_B\Desktop"` or even custom directories like `"D:\MyFiles\Desktop"`) that varies depending on the machine. So is there a built-in "function" (eg. `%userprofile%` to go to the user's folder or `%systemroot%` to go to the Windows folder under C drive) that tells the script to reach for the actual location of the current user's desktop?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can find is `%userprofile%\desktop`

Not sure if it works when the desktop is redirected to a different drive.

Also if the script needs to be run as a different user (say admin) it would just point to admin\desktop.